# can't load raw files in to gimp version installed by snapd on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ppa, snap, gimp

When I installed 20.04 I loaded the version of Gimp from the ppa and everything worked with the .config files I brought across from 18.04.  I had to reinstall the system, probably due to an error I made, this time I forgot the ppa so got snapd version of gimp.  I have been unable to get that version to load camera raw files with **darktable** (or anything else for that matter). I am now beginning to think this is imposable so have reverted to the ppa.

Comment: What do you mean by *unable to ..  load camera raw files with darktable*? The "snap" version is sandboxed and will only read/write files under your home directory tree. But adding plugins may be difficult too.

Comment: That my point gimp is a program that uses plugins to some considerable extent. So I wonder way it was considered a candidate for snapd. At present I can still find the .deb files though I have had to hold-back a library file it uses.